# How to login using different user in perforce? Is there any way so that we can login to a different user using the Superuser in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I need to submit changes through different user. So, for that I need to be logged in as that user. How to do that using a superuser?

Answer (score 2):

Read here: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_login.html

```
Helix Server superusers can obtain login tickets for users other 
than themselves without entering passwords. Non-superusers who 
attempt to log in as other users must use the 'p4 -u username login' 
form of the command and correctly supply the other user’s password.
```